# How to get the access token from facebook's oauth redirect in python?

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-apps

I'm new to FB app development. Once the user authorize my app, facebook does the following request 

`http://www.example.com/response#access_token=...&expires_in=3600`



Now my python do not see the part after the '#'. How do i get the part, or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use this. That is part of **client side** auth. URI fragments (the stuff after the #) are never sent to the server by the browser. You need to look up [server side auth](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to fill in YOUR_URL in `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL`, next the facebook app (in python) needs to filter the return URL and yank out the access_token in the callback.

For more information, drop by https://apps.facebook.com/fileglu/technical - i am using facebook's access_token and dropbox's access_token to enable dropbox access inside Facebook App.

Have hooks for Google Oauth 2.0, anyone requires google docs access within Facebook?